# Coursera : unknown signal 11 by autograder

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, subsequence

I have this piece of code for Longest Common Sub-sequence problem (I am doing it by Dynamic Programming method)

But I am getting error by the Coursera Autograder (Failed case #6/37: unknown signal 11 (Time used: 0.00/1.00, memory used: 9166848/536870912.))

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int max(int a,int b)
{

    return a>b?a:b;
}

int common_sub_sequence(vector<int> &arr1, vector<int> &arr2, int n, int m)
{

    int ch[m + 1][n + 1]={0}; 
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++) 
        { 
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            {
                ch[i][j] = 0; 
            }
        
            else if (arr1[i - 1] == arr2[j - 1])
            {
                ch[i][j] = ch[i - 1][j - 1] + 1; 
            }
        
            else
            {
                ch[i][j] = max(ch[i - 1][j], ch[i][j - 1]);
            }
        } 
    } 
    return ch[n][m];
}

int main()
{

    int  n=0, m=0;
    cin>>n;

    vector<int>arr1(n,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    cin >> m;
    vector<int>arr2(m,0);
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        cin >> arr2[j];
    }
    cout << common_sub_sequence( arr1 , arr2, n, m) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How could I remove that error ???

Comment: probably not the issue, but variable length arrays like `int ch[m + 1][n + 1]={0};` are not supported by standard C++

Comment: Unknown Signal 11 is likely a segmentation fault. The program tried to access a resource it does not own. Check to ensure all of your array accesses are in bounds. `vector` has an `at` method that performs bounds checking that can help you out here.

Comment: Unrelated: Your program will compile much much much faster if you only include the headers you need. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` includes all of the Standard library headers, and this gets very very expensive.

Comment: The Standard issue raised by @StephanLechner can easily result in a stack overflow and a Stack Overflow can often lead to segmentation faults. Actually, segfault is about the nicest thing a stack overflow will do for you, so you should thank it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues that can lead to undefined behaviour;

First, you create an array of size `ch[m+1][n+1]`, but the outer loop is `for (i=0; i<=n; i++)`, accessing `ch[i][j]`. The size is `m+1`, but you iterate until `i<=n` (note the *n* - *m* - difference). So it should be

```
int ch[n+1][m+1]`
```

Second, you create a variable length array as a local variable. If supported at all, it will be created on the "stack" and might exceed stack limits for large values of m and n. You could overcome this with

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > ch(n+1, std::vector<int>(m+1));
```